# How to update crontab for a user with a script without duplicating comments

Tags: bash, cron

So I've noticed that I've dumped a lot of annoying comments in the top of quite a few crontab files by using

```
crontab -u user -l > /tmp/crontab.user
#muck with the file
crontab -u user /tmp/crontab.user
```

and now I'm stuck with

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
```

and two other lines repeated over and over again in the top of my crontab files.

I'd like to get rid of these by doing something like

```
crontab -u user -l > /tmp/crontab.user
#muck with the file
#clean up the file
crontab -u user /tmp/crontab.user
```

but I'm not really sure what I should do to clean remove groups of three comment lines here safely.  I'm guessing some sort of `sed` + `tail` combo is in order.  Or just a perl one-liner.

Comment: Probably something like `crontab -u user -l | sed '/^#.*/d' | crontab -u user`?

Comment: @dope, I've got comments above every legit line in there, otherwise that'd work, but thanks, I think it was the "/d" part of sed that I was forgetting about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanup script can look something like

```
sed -i '/^# DO NOT EDIT.*\|^# (.*/d' /tmp/crontab.user
```

because your version of cron at least puts `# DO NOT EDIT` and `# (` in at the header part and you never use things that start like that in any of your managed code (and if anyone else does, they'll be sorry)